# Simple downloader

Tags: download, file-download

I would like to send an iso image for a friend. Normal IE download doesn't work, she has an instable and slow internet connection.

A dedicated downloader application would be perfect. She starts an .exe, and this app can resume/restart the download.

Saddly, but FTP or torrent is not an alternative.

Comment: unless the sending server supports resuming downloads i do not believe the software will matter. someone correct me if i am mistaken.

Comment: I'm able to install/configure my server for the needs, I'm looking for a client. I.e.: for a Single-Click-FTP-Downloader or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If she cannot install anything on the laptop, you could upload the .ISO to some web space, or host it on IIS on your computer (forwarding port 80 from your router).

You then email her [**wget**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), which she saves on the desktop.  She then has to open a CMD prompt (assuming that is not locked out as well), and types in:

```
cd %userprofile%\desktop
wget -c http://yourwebspacedomain.com/youriso.iso
```

Alternatively, you can use [**cURL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) in the same way, using an FTP server.

```
cd %userprofile%\desktop
curl -o youriso.iso ftp://ftp.yourftpserver.com/youriso.iso
```

to resume:

```
curl -C - -o youriso.iso ftp://ftp.yourftpserver.com/youriso.iso
```

(case sensitive)

Comment: A good addition to this recipe would be to provide a checksum for the ISO file as well and a way to check the file integrity after it will be downloaded. There are standalone versions of md5sum and sha1sum programs. Given the complexity of the situation due to restriction, it will be a shame to get a broken ISO.

Comment: @vtest: I agree, but I think it may have been too complicated for the user that was downloading this particular .iso.  Including both .exe files along with ready-made batch script would work very nicely though.  It could be executed to start the download, resume it and check its integrity at the end.

Answer (score 4):

An easy and reliable way would be for you to both install **Dropbox** (free).

Comment: I like Dropbox but she is not able to install new programs, and 250Mb it's not enough for this iso.

Comment: @boj: the referral link gives you 250MB of extra space, making 2.25GB in total, which you can extend by making referrals.

Comment: oh, thanx...i'll try wget and than this.

Answer (score 1):

IE does not resume downloads, but [Firefox does:](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/features/)

```
The resume function also works if your system crashes or is forced to restart.
```

This will work as long as the server hosting the file also supports resume, of which most do nowadays.

Comment: yes, it would be the preferred way - but she can't install on the corporate notebook.

Comment: Try the portable version. http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable